# ComboBox to type on specific window

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I can't figure out how to make my ComboBox (which lists all open windows(I can see these already)) to make my form type on that selected window. I just can't make it so when screen1 is selected, it clicks on that screen.

Example:
I have 2 different forms open.
Form (1) clicks on a specified screen. (screen1)
Form (2) clicks on a different specified screen. (screen2)

The forms are the same program just opened twice.

I want my form to be able to click on a certain screen even if it's not open.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Diagnostics
Public Class W1


Public Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal lpEnumFunc As EnumWindowsProc, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Int32
Public Declare Function IsWindowVisible Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
Public Delegate Function EnumWindowsProc(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Boolean
Public Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32.dll" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Int32) As Int32
Public Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32.dll" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Int32
Public Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32.dll" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Int32) As Int32
Public Declare Function GetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal intptr As IntPtr) As IntPtr
Private Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpRect As RECT) As Boolean
Public Property SelectedItem As Object
Public Const GWL_HWNDPARENT As Int32 = -8
Private newwindowlist As List(Of String)
Private newhandlelist As List(Of IntPtr)

Private Structure RECT
    Public left As Integer
    Public top As Integer
    Public right As Integer
    Public bottom As Integer
    Public Sub New(ByVal _left As Integer, ByVal _top As Integer, ByVal _right As Integer, ByVal _bottom As Integer)
        left = _left
        top = _top
        right = _right
        bottom = _bottom
    End Sub
End Structure

Private Function EnumWinProc(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Boolean
    If IsWindowVisible(hwnd) Then
        If GetParent(hwnd) = IntPtr.Zero Then
            If GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HWNDPARENT) = 0 Then
                Dim str As String = String.Empty.PadLeft(GetWindowTextLength(hwnd) + 1)
                GetWindowText(hwnd, str, str.Length)
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1)) Then
                    newwindowlist.Add(str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    EnumWinProc = True
End Function

Private Sub RefreshWindowList()
    newwindowlist = New List(Of String)
    EnumWindows(AddressOf EnumWinProc, CInt(True))
End Sub
```

And

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    RefreshWindowList()
    For Each item As String In newwindowlist
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(item)
        ComboBox1.SelectedItem = Convert.ToInt64(GWL_HWNDPARENT)
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Comment: __I want my form to be able to click on a certain screen even if it's not open.__ Even if what is not open? You can not target a window that does not exist, nor can you run code from within a form that is not instanciated.

Comment: I meant that the window is open, just not at the top. Like it's behind my browser. The window itself is open.

Comment: Can you explain your end goal for sending clicks to other windows, and how you are doing that? Are you simply trying to switch the active (foremost) window, or do you want to perform actions in the background?

Comment: I want to perform actions in the background.
There is a couple games that I wish to autoclick, so I can have 2 games running, and clicks constantly on each game seperately (of course with 2 of my programs running)

Comment: My main problem is getting my program to listen to what is selected. The game website is recognized in my dropdown box, but when I switch it to "game1" the only clicks I get are on the topmost open window, rather then in the game that is minimized in the background

Comment: So how are you sending your click events? I don't see anything in the posted code indicating your method. Are you sending Messages through the Windows Message API?

Comment: I just need to know how to make it so I can autoclick in a different window? thanks.

Comment: Can't help you unless I know how you intend to send those clicks...

Comment: I've changed it to make it so it types things.

http://pastebin.com/QkbijV7M

Comment: The SendKeys function is great for emulating user-input, but it only works on the currently active window or program (it literally emulates user input, as if the user were typing on the keyboard). You really need to look into the Windows Message API if you want to send events in the background.