# Autotyper only types on selected window

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am relatively new to VB. Honestly below is mainly from reading tutorials.

What I'm trying to create is an autotyper that can type on the selected window in my ComboBox.
Right now, it get's the windows title in the ComboBox and I can select one, but when I click start on my autotyper, it only types on the screen that is currently at the top. I want it to be able to only type on the screen that is selected, even if the program is in the background. My only problem is getting my program to type on the window that is selected in the ComboBox.

I've searched about SelectItem but can't find where to put the code, let alone know what to put there. I've literally searched different things for 2 days straight and couldn't figure anything out even with the help of a friend.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class W1

Public Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal lpEnumFunc As EnumWindowsProc, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Int32
Public Declare Function IsWindowVisible Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
Public Delegate Function EnumWindowsProc(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Boolean
Public Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32.dll" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Int32) As Int32
Public Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32.dll" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Int32
Public Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32.dll" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Int32) As Int32
Public Declare Function GetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal intptr As IntPtr) As IntPtr
Private Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpRect As RECT) As Boolean
Public Property SelectedItem As Object

Public Const GWL_HWNDPARENT As Int32 = -8
Private newwindowlist As List(Of String)
Private newhandlelist As List(Of IntPtr)

Private Structure RECT
    Public left As Integer
    Public top As Integer
    Public right As Integer
    Public bottom As Integer
    Public Sub New(ByVal _left As Integer, ByVal _top As Integer, ByVal _right As Integer, ByVal _bottom As Integer)
        left = _left
        top = _top
        right = _right
        bottom = _bottom
    End Sub
End Structure

Private Function EnumWinProc(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Boolean
    If IsWindowVisible(hwnd) Then
        If GetParent(hwnd) = IntPtr.Zero Then
            If GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HWNDPARENT) = 0 Then
                Dim str As String = String.Empty.PadLeft(GetWindowTextLength(hwnd) + 1)
                GetWindowText(hwnd, str, str.Length)
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1)) Then
                    newwindowlist.Add(str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    EnumWinProc = True
End Function

Private Sub RefreshWindowList()
    newwindowlist = New List(Of String)
    EnumWindows(AddressOf EnumWinProc, CInt(True))
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    RefreshWindowList()
    For Each item As String In newwindowlist
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    SendKeys.Send(TextBox1.Text)
    SendKeys.Send("{Enter}")
End Sub

Private Sub StartButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StartButton.Click
    Timer1.Interval = TextBox2.Text * 1000
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub StopButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StopButton.Click
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ComboBox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ComboBox to type on specific window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644843/combobox-to-type-on-specific-window)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you click on the botton on your program, focus is there, not on the other window anymore. SendKeys always works against the window/control with focus, just like you were typing on a keyboard.

If you were typing a letter in MS Word, then clicked on Notepad, and continued to type, you wouldn't expect to be typing in MS Word. This is the same thing.

What you want to do is use something like [AppActivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyz95fhy.aspx) to activate the window you want first. This takes a window name or process id, and it looks like you know how to get those already.

Comment: I figured out how to work that, but when I hit the start button, the window selected is activated, but when I click off it keeps coming back into focus. How can I make it so the window I select still receives my text even if the window isnt open? So like it still runs in the background?

Comment: If the window is not visible and active, SENDKEYS() will not send keys to it. You could try DDE if the other program supports it.